# Origine de l'expression « sans autre » en Suisse

Tags: expressions, régionalismes, suisse, origine-ou-raison

en Suisse, l'expression *sans autre* s'emploie dans le sens de *sans hésiter*,

par exemple, « vous pouvez sans autre me téléphoner demain ».

Je me demandais quelle était l'origine de cette expression ?

Comment: Cette expression signifie "sans problème".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il semble que c'est un raccourci pour l'[expression](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sans_autre_forme_de_proc%C3%A8s) **sans autre forme de procès** (variante : *sans autre formalité*), raccourci qui n'est effectivement employé qu'en Suisse.

Answer (score 4):

J'ai remarqué que souvent, les expressions suisses sont une traduction littéraire de certaines expressions italiennes: dans ce cas, par exemple, je pense à la formule italienne "senz'altro", qui est utilisée exactement comme le "sans autre" suisse.

Comment: Cela marche aussi pour l'allemand : après s'être habitué aux suissismes, il est plus facile d’apprendre l'Allemand car certaines tournures de phrases deviennent logiques.